# Send SMS/MMS, especially MMS using .Net w C#

Tags: c#, .net, sms, gsm, mms

Does anyone know how to send an MMS message with the .net framework? Theres sample code for SMS but not MMS. I have a GPRS modem already installed on my server.

Comment: Which GPRS modem did you use, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any easy way to do this natively in .NET without writing your own code to do the SMS/MMS encoding and decoding. You could try one of the following libraries:

- [IPWorks SMS Component](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/smpp.aspx)
- [MM7.NET MMS Library](http://www.inetlab.ru/Products/MM7.aspx)
- [C# MMS Library](http://twit88.com/platform/projects/show/mt-mms)

Answer (score 1):

For GPRS modem,

Sending SMS will be through AT commands, sending MMS is through MM1 protocol.

There are few libraries available that you can use for both SMS and MMS sending if you do not want to write your own code

MessagingToolkit from twit88.com

Activexperts SMS and MMS

NowSMS

so far the only native .NET solution is messagingtoolkit. The others can be used for .NET as well they are COM components.

Answer (score 0):

Also, depending on your mobile handset, for example, Nokia, for selected specific models, one could pull down a library to interact with the handset via data cable (USB/Serial), and depending on the supplied documentation, there may be an activex dll which you can `tlbimp` the activex to get the wrappers and invoke the methods/functions/events while the data cable is connected to it. My experience was with an rather old handset Nokia 3330, and used the Nokia suite, to send SMS.

This will be dependant on the handset/GPRS modem used, the manufacturer may not tell you how to use it so a bit of trial and error will be necessary...sorry if this is not an exact answer you are looking for...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.